# characters from {{}}. is garbled. How can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

This is Laravel blade.
I would like to put URL in request.open.

```
<script>
    function fetchData(){
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

 request.open('GET',{{ route('test')}} , true);
 request.responseType = 'json';

 request.onload = function () {
   var data = this.response;
   console.log(data);
 };

 request.send();
    }
</script>
```

I've noticed  url should be 'https://~'.
I modified like this

```
 request.open('GET',{{"'"}}{{ route('test')}}{{"'"}} , true);
```

but then
it will be

```
 request.open('GET',&#039;http://localhost:8000/slip/test&#039;  , true);
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Just `request.open('GET', "{{ route('test')}}" , true);`

Answer (score 1):

just try this

```
<script>
    function fetchData(){
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        request.open('GET',"{{ route('test')}}" , true);
        request.responseType = 'json';

        request.onload = function () {
        var data = this.response;
        console.log(data);
    };

     request.send();
    }
</script>
```